# How to merge and sort lists of different lengths without sort functions?

Tags: python, list

Python homework. I have to create a function that will be called into the main function. I've just barely made something that passes, but I want to know better way. I still haven't learned what a merge algorithm "O(log N))" even is. The assignment is to merge 2 pre-sorted lists into a single sorted list, without using sort() or other similar methods. Any sorting algorithms are also discouraged from being made.

```
    number1 = [0, 2, 3]
    number2 = [1, 4, 5, 6, 9]
    retlist = merge(number1, number2)
    print(retlist)
```

What I make also has to work regardless of which list is longer, or if the values are completely random.

After almost literally 2 days this was finally something that the auto-grade accepted.

```
def merge(number1, number2):
    #I can only type here
    mlist = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(number1) and j < len(number2):
        if number1[i] < number2[j]:
            mlist.append(number1[i])
            i = i + 1
        elif number2[j] < number1[i]:
            mlist.append(number2[j])
            j = j + 1
    x = mlist[-1] + 1
    if len(number2) > len(number1):
        y = number2.index(x)
        mlist.extend(number2[y:])
    elif len(number1) > len(number2):
        y = number1.index(x)
        mlist.extend(number1[y:])
    return mlist
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this, while considering the restrictions being applied. How would a real merge and sort algorithm look like?

edit: Forgot to paste the return statement. Also here is the real conditions that my function needed to satisfy, I just forget it's in a different location.

```
def test_main_2():
    n1 = [random.randint(0, 20) for i in range(5)]
    n2 = [random.randint(0, 20) for i in range(3)]
    n1.sort()
    n2.sort()
    tlist = n1 + n2
    tlist.sort()
    print('Test data')
    print(n1)
    print(n2)
    retlist = main.merge(n1, n2)
    print('After merge', retlist)
    print(tlist)
    print(retlist)
    assert tlist == retlist
```

There are a few others but they just make sure that sort() isn't being used and other similar things.

Comment: That was accepted? Extremely surprising, given all its bugs.

Comment: Could you please list any? I'm still struggling to learn and haven't found anything that really teaches me.

Comment: A merge algorithm, definitionally, is `O(n)`, not `O(log n)`, it has to produce all the values. Crazy tricks with bisecting might reduce the number of comparisons a small amount in certain cases (where long runs are taken from one input before any are taken from the other), but it would still be `O(n)`. General purpose sorts are `O(n log n)`, so merging existing sorted data is cheaper than sorting from scratch on an asymptotic basis, but neither of them is as cheap as `O(log n)`.

Comment: @Maverick For starters, you're not returning anything, so it's completely obvious that your code was *not* accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a production quality merge and sort algorithm, you can always check [the implementation of `heapq.merge`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a77fa0512466bfd6edbab2aa3c830cdd1b0f5ba8/Lib/heapq.py#L316), which ships with Python. It does more than you strictly need (handling the merging of an arbitrary number of iterables, not just two, supporting the `key` and `reverse` arguments that `list.sort`/`sorted` support, and producing a lazy iterator of results rather than eagerly constructing a merged `list`), so you could strip it down to eliminate the unnecessary parts of it for a simpler solution, but that's the basic idea.

The simple form of it is that it:

1. Produces an iterator from each source
2. It draws one element from each source up front, and stores the paired drawn element with the source iterator
3. In a loop, it chooses the smallest drawn element to put in the merged output, then tries to replace that element with a new one drawn from the corresponding source iterator, and repeats this step
4. Once all but one iterator have been exhausted, it blindly produces whatever remains from the remaining iterator (no more merging needed, everything left is definitionally after everything else already produced)

Comment: I *love* iterators, but here I think they should just fix their attempt, sticking with indices. They have so much trouble already that I doubt switching to a new concept (that I think is more difficult for beginners) would help them.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, I was not in any way suggesting they should *use* this for their solution. They asked: 1) Is there a better way to do this? and 2) What a real merge and sort algorithm would look like? This is the answer. They can learn what they can from it right now, and maybe later on they'll understand more and can learn more, that's all.

Comment: Meh, the answer to 1) is *"Yes, any correct way is better"* :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the requirement is that you should implement this without the aid of any utility modules. If that's the case then:

```
def merge(n1, n2):
    assert sorted(n1) == n1
    assert sorted(n2) == n2
    if not n1:
        return n2
    if not n2:
        return n1
    output = []
    i = j = 0
    while True:
        if n1[i] < n2[j]:
            output.append(n1[i])
            if (i := i + 1) == len(n1):
                output.extend(n2[j:])
                break
        else:
            output.append(n2[j])
            if (j := j + 1) == len(n2):
                output.extend(n1[i:])
                break
    return output

print(merge([0,2,3],[1, 4, 5, 6, 9]))
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying out your code, I did a bit of simple refactoring, building a simple brute force bubble sort loop within the function.

```
def merge(number1, number2):
    
    mlist = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(number1):         # Add in the elements from the first list to the work list
        mlist.append(number1[i])
        i = i + 1   
    
    i = 0      

    while i < len(number2):         # Add in the elements from the second list to the work list
        mlist.append(number2[i])
        i = i + 1   

    i = 1

    while (i == 1):                 # Replicating a crude brute force bubble sort
        i = 0                       # This will remain "0" once no more swapping of values occurs
        j = 0
        while j < (len(mlist) - 1):
            if mlist[j] > mlist[j + 1]:
                temp = mlist[j]
                mlist[j] = mlist[j + 1]
                mlist[j + 1] = temp
                i = 1               # Note that a swap took place and another possible run through the list may be needed
            j = j + 1

    return mlist

number1 = [0, 2, 3]
number2 = [1, 4, 5, 6, 9]

print(merge(number1, number2))      # Just called the function from within the print statement
```

Following are some key points.

- First off, the work list in the function is just initially built by appending all of the elements from the first list and appending all of the elements from the second list prior to any sorting.
- In lieu of using a statement such as "mlist.sort(), a use of a variable as a Boolean flag is set and evaluated as multiple while loop iterations are performed to effectively execute a simplistic bubble sort.
- Once no more element swapping is sensed, the outer while loop will be exited and the total sorted list would be returned.

Using your example lists, following was the terminal output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/MergeList$ python3 MergeList.py 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

I am not sure if your instructor will like that any better, but go ahead and review the refactored code.

Comment: The question states "merge 2 pre-sorted lists" so why have you implemented  a sort?